# How to prove that $r_n=r_{n-1} - \frac12 b r_{n-1}^2 $ is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: asymptotics, recursion

So my question is:

How do we prove that $r_n=r_{n-1} -\frac12 b r_{n-1}^2 $ is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{n}$ when we have an offspring distribution $p_i:=P(\xi=i)$ and b is the variance
$$b=\sum_{i\geq 2}i(i-1) p_i< \infty$$ and $r_n:=1-q^n(0)$ for $$q^n(x):=q(q^{n-1}(x)), \quad q(x):=p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2+\ldots,$$
what gives us $$r_1=1-p_0.$$
Also we have
$$\sum_{i\geq 1}i p_i=1.$$

Best regards!

Edit: In fact it is asymptotic to $\frac{2}{bn}$.

Comment: If $b$ is sufficiently large (say $b = 5$ for $r_1 = 1$) then this will definitely just explode to negative infinity.

Comment: Yeah, right... Mhm. I am reading an old paper from Kolmogorov (On the solution of a problem in biology) and what he says is this:
$\frac{r_n}{r_{n-1}}=1-\frac12 br_{n-1} + O(r_{n-2}^2)$ gives us $r_n \sim \frac{2}{nb}$.  In this special case $b$ is the variance of a critical offspring distribution.
$r_n $ is defined by $r_n=1-q^{(n)}(0)$ and $q^{(n+1)}(x):=q(q^n(x))$ for $q^1(x):=p_0+p_1x+p_2x^2+...$.

Comment: This looks true under the form "asymptotic to $K \dfrac{1}{n}$" (K=constant) for the very narrow range $b \in (0,1)$ (and $r_1 \in (0,1)$). Do like (good) journalists : check your sources !

Comment: Ok so $r_1\in (0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$, thx!

But: $b\in(0,1)$ seems like a problem. Kolmogorov only chooses $b>0$. So I am missing something or that's an old fault...

Comment: For $r_1$ it is unimportant, but you cannot say $b \in (0,\infty)$ : if I take b=3, 4, 5, 6..., the sequence explodes

Comment: The adequate domain for $b$ looks to be $(0,2)$. This issue may be connected to the logistic map : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map

Comment: Ok, but if we define $r$ with this $q$ we get $r_1=1-\sum_{i\geq 0}p_i$ and because $b$ is the variance we get $b=\sum_{i\geq 2} i(i-1)p_i$.  I will add this to the question, maybe that's what is missing.

Comment: So, I added the missing relation between $r_n$ and b.

Comment: So I added everything we could eventually use. I simplified the problem a bit too much... Sorry.

Comment: @JeanMarie, This is not the same situation as the logistic map, which is induced by the iteration $x \mapsto bx(1-x)$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Don't you think that it can be amenable to it by a change of variable ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, If I substitute $s_n = \frac{b}{2}r_n$, then $s_n$ will satisfy $s_n = s_{n-1}(1-s_{n-1})$. I agree that this is a logistic map, but we will not have explosion if $s_1$ is small...

Comment: Of course it should be  $r_1=1-p_0.$

Comment: So maybe it would be okay to just say we want to proove that $r_n  \sim \frac{2}{n\cdot b}$ holds, so we put that in the equation $\frac{r_n}{r_{n-1}} = 1-\frac12 b +O(r_{n-1}^2)$ and we get $1-\frac{1}{n} = 1- \frac{1}{n-1} + O(\frac{1}{(n-1)^2})$ and that's true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $q(x) = \mathbf{E}[x^{\xi}]$. If $\mathbf{E}[\xi] = 1$ and $b = \mathbf{Var}(\xi) \in (0, \infty)$, then

- $r_n = 1 - q^{\circ n}(0)$ solves $r_n = 1 - q(1 - r_{n-1})$, hence decreases to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.
- By the Taylor's theorem, $1-q(1-h) = h - \left(\frac{b}{2}+o(1)\right)h^2$.

So, if we write $a_n = \frac{1}{r_n}$, then

$$a_{n}
= a_{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{\frac{b}{2}+o(1)}{a_{n-1}} \right)^{-1}
= a_{n-1} + \frac{b}{2} + o(1). $$

Using this, we can prove that $a_n = \left( \frac{b}{2} + o(1) \right) n$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: How do you get  $a_{n}
= a_{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{\frac{b}{2}+o(1)}{a_{n-1}} \right)^{-1}
= a_{n-1} + \frac{b}{2} + o(1). $? Should it be $a_{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{\frac{b}{2}+o(1)}{a_{n-1}} \right)$?

But I get: 
$a_n=\frac{1}{r_n}= \frac{1}{r_{n-1} - \frac12 br_{n-1}^2 } = a_{n-1} \cdot  \frac{1}{1 - \frac12 br_{n-1} }$

Comment: @cptflint, I utilized $1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots$.

Comment: Okay! Thank you!

Comment: Mhm, I think we missed something. In every step we add $a_{n-1}o(1)$ so how can we proove the asymptotic behavior?

Comment: @cptflint, This is a typical application of [*Stolz–Cesàro theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). Since $a_n - a_{n-1} \to \frac{b}{2}$ as $n\to\infty$, by Stolz–Cesàro theorem, $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{n - (n-1)} = \frac{b}{2}. $$

Comment: Okay, thx! But then there is one problem left: 

If we taylor, we get something like: $r_n= r_{n-1} -\frac12 \sigma^2 r_{n-1}^2 + O(r_{n-1}^3)$, but you say $o(1)$? And for me it seems like $o(1)$ is really what we need, right? Otherwise we won't have $a_n-a_{n-1} \rightarrow \frac{b}{2}$. 

Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @cptflint, $o(1)$-term follows from the explicit expression of the remainder term of the 2nd-order Taylor approximation. If we assume that $\xi$ has 3rd moment, then one can indeed prove that $r_n = r_{n-1} - \frac{b}{2}r_{n-1}^2 + \mathcal{O}(r_{n-1}^3)$, but this is in general not true only assuming finite 2nd-moment condition.

Comment: Yeah okay, but how do we get $o(1)$? That is not obvious for me, because that means it is tending to zero. Sorry, I am a somewhat confused.

Comment: @cptflint, I think you have a valid point, I was a bit careless when claiming that finite second moment condition for $\xi$ is enough to have $o(1)$ term. At least $C^2$-regularity for $q$ on $[0, 1]$ will be enough.

Comment: Okay so we could assume finite 3rd moment and get $O(r_{n-1}^3)$ which is $o(1)$ because the population will die out almost surely and then we can do your calculation, right?